# Setfill and setw not working

Tags: c++, iomanip, setw

Basically I am trying to setfill and setw to create a fixed table to display information stored in an array however it doesn't appear that set width is working and I'm not sure why. Here is the code I am using:

```
const int MAXWIDTH = 10;
cout << left << setw(MAXWIDTH) << setfill(' ') << "Stock Number";
cout << left << setw(MAXWIDTH) << setfill(' ') << "Stock Description";
cout << left << setw(MAXWIDTH) << setfill(' ') << "Order Level";
cout << left << setw(MAXWIDTH) << setfill(' ') << "Reorder Level";
```

The output I get is:

[image]

Comment: It is unnecessary to use `left` and `setfill` manipulators each time. You can use them once before streaming everything.

Comment: The constant named `MAXWIDTH` should be named `MINWIDTH`.

Answer (score 1):

Either increase the column width or use two rows.
The "Stock Description" has more than 10 letters.
You should also allow for spaces between column titles.